# MapStruct to not generate mappings for fields marked with specific annotation

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm dealing with framework code that I cannot modify and which ends up throwing a `NullPointerException` during mapping because MapStruct thinks it should use a getter defined in a superclass.

Is there a way to tell MapStruct to ignore all getters marked with `@JsonIgnore` (a jackson library annotation) ?

---

## Some more context

To provide a bit of code, here is part of the generated implementation by MapStruct:

```java
        if ( target.getChangedProperties() != null ) {
            target.getChangedProperties().clear();
            List<Property> list = src.getChangedProperties();
            if ( list != null ) {
                target.getChangedProperties().addAll( list );
            }
        }
```

The NPE is thrown from within `target.getChangedProperties()` because there are some uninitialized variables being accessed. However, in reality, **I don't even want this getter to be part of MapStruct's implementation**. (In fact, that getter isn't a getter for a specific variable, but more of a "utility getter", so I do wonder why MapStruct is trying to use it.)

My mapped class would look like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity extends TheFrameworkSuperClass {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String foo;
}
```

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class TheFrameworkSuperClass {

    @Version
    @JsonProperty(value = "Version")
    private Long version;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    protected UnitOfWorkChangeSet changes;

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Property> getChangedProperties() {
        // stuff happening before
        this.changes.getObjectChangeSetForClone(this); // throws NPE
        // stuff happening after
    }
}
```

### My MapStruct interface

I have no customization of the mapper's configs. And my interface is:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    MyEntity boToBo(MyEntity destination);

    void updateBo(MyEntity src, @MappingTarget MyEntity target);
}
```

I contemplated using `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)` and then listing each field individually to make sure no extra getters are used, but that is far from being a satisfying solution due to the amount of times I'll have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out even though the `changedProperties` field does not exist, since MapStruct picks up `getChangedProperties()` as a getter, you can nonetheless tell MapStruct to ignore that non-existing field...

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "changedProperties", ignore = true)
    MyEntity boToBo(MyEntity destination);

    @Mapping(target = "changedProperties", ignore = true)
    void updateBo(MyEntity src, @MappingTarget MyEntity target);
}
```

Comment: Just do add some more context to this. MapStruct does not look at fields. MapStruct looks at properties as they are defined by the Java Bean specification and it also support public fieds and Java records now.